# Random number gen- Undeclared identifier

Tags: c, random, identifier

I have poorly put together part of a program- code so far

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE 1024
#define IDM_FILE_RUN 40001
#define IDM_APP_EXIT 40002

//Window Function
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, 
               LPSTR lpszArgs, int nWinMode)
{

WNDCLASS wcls;
HWND hwnd;
MSG msg;

// Name of window and window class
LPCWSTR szWinName   = L"Threads Program";
LPCWSTR szClassName = L"ThreadsProgram";


wcls.hInstance = hThisInst;
wcls.lpszClassName = szClassName;
wcls.lpfnWndProc = WindowFunc;
wcls.style = 0;
wcls.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wcls.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcls.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wcls.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcls.cbWndExtra = 0;
wcls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);

// Register windows class
if(!RegisterClass(&wcls))
{
    return 0;
}

// Create main window
hwnd = CreateWindow(szClassName,
    szWinName,
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    100,
    100,
    400,
    400,
    HWND_DESKTOP,
    NULL,
    hThisInst,
    NULL );

// Show main window
ShowWindow(hwnd, nWinMode);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);

// Message loop
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
return (int)msg.wParam;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hMainWindow, UINT message, 
                        WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
static char textBuffer[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
static int nRead;


switch(message)    
{
case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HMENU hMenu;
        HMENU hMenuPopup;

        // create menus
        hMenu = CreateMenu();
        hMenuPopup = CreateMenu();

        // populate menus
        AppendMenu(hMenuPopup, MF_STRING,  IDM_FILE_RUN,   L"&Choose Balls");   
        AppendMenu(hMenuPopup, MF_STRING,  IDM_APP_EXIT,   L"&Exit");  
        AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hMenuPopup,   L"&File");

        // attach menus to main window
        SetMenu(hMainWindow, hMenu);
    }
    break;
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        // Obey command
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDM_FILE_RUN:

            {
                srand (time(NULL));
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    printf ("%i\n", (rand ()% 49) + 1);  




    return 0;

            }
            break;
        case IDM_APP_EXIT:
            SendMessage(hMainWindow, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hMainWindow, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}// Window function
```

The error messages say i have an undeclared identifier and its in relation to my random number part,

```
case IDM_FILE_RUN:              
            {
                srand (time(NULL));
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    printf ("%i\n", (rand ()% 49) + 1);  

                return 0;
            }
```

Im unsure what i need to write and where i need to write it to fix it.

Thanks

```
Error   9   error C2059: syntax error : ')' 108 1
Error   6   error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier    108 1
Error   8   error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier    108 1
Error   4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'   108 1
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'   108 1
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'   108 1
Error   5   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'   108 1
```

Comment: What is the exact error message ?

Comment: Also, is all of the posted code necessary for the question? I'm thinking more along the lines of [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: 7 error messages

syntax error ')'
undeclared identifier 'i' (twice)
syntax error ')'before type
syntax error ';'before type (three times)

Comment: I'm sure that it would be easy to get an answer if you post the _complete_ error messages in the body of the question.

Comment: Sorry im not sure whether all the posted code is necessary.

Comment: i dont know how to post the complete error messages in the body of the question.

Comment: @GennySaxo You should be able to simply copy and paste your message from where it occurs (terminal window?) to the post above.

Comment: Yes sorry i do and have done, i was highlighting them incorrectly before and thats why i couldnt.

Comment: @GennySaxo I would concentrate on locating the first error in that list, I bet the others are caused by this, ie cascading errors.

Comment: Yes i agree, i did think it was just 1 error, i thought it was something to do with declaring the 'i' somehow, but the first error line 108, is the for statement line and i keep looking at it and i cannot see how i can be missing a ')' ive looked above and below also, as i was told before to do that, and it looks exactly the same as it does in the video where i got that segment of code from.

Comment: @GennySaxo See if my answer helps, if not, we have eliminated one possible source of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be a long-shot, but change your current for loops to look like this:

```
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    ...
```

it may be that your compiler doesn't like declaring the variable inside the `for` (mine doesn't unless I give it a special command line option)

Comment: yes thats helped as it now compiles with the int i; above the srand line, when it was above the for line, it still came up with errors. Although it compiles it is not displaying the numbers, the original code worked in a console, would the output line be the same for a windowed program?

Comment: @GennySaxo Sorry, I don't know the answer to that .. you may have to look around for that information where you are getting the code from.

Comment: Declaring a variable in a for loop, like `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++)` is a new feature in the C99 standard. Microsoft's compiler doesn't support C99. And @GennySaxo: telling us "it still came up with errors" is less than helpful; you need to tell us exactly *what* the errors are. Possibly you should post a new question.